Copy rest position pose to another armature
I have multiple armatures, all with the same amount of bones and bone names, but different bone positions that I want to combine into a pose library. The issue is that I can't apply the bone positions given all the armatures have their own rest positions. What I'm trying to do is something similar to how the join as shapes tool works for shape keys, but is applied to armatures.
